# How to add my custom addons that i've created in Odoo 15 in Docker container?

Tags: docker, odoo

How to add my custom addons that i've created in Odoo 15 in Docker container? i already installed Odoo 15 in Docker

Comment: you should add the clone command in the docker file of your GitHub account and recreate the container there must be a path created with custom addons if not, then you have to create a custom addon folder and change the config accordingly in the docker file, 
you can also add it in existing, but it's useless as next time you run, it won't have the addon you added

Comment: Can you tell me the steps to do the operation on another plateform like what's app where it would be easier ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a volume that points where the module is stored. In order to add the volume using `docker`:

`$ docker run -v /path/to/addons:/mnt/extra-addons -p 8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo`

[Source here](https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo#:%7E:text=db%2Dfilter%3Dodoo_db_.*-,Mount%20custom%20addons,-You%20can%20mount)

I recommend using `docker-compose` with all the commands in a `*.yaml` file.

[Here](https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo#:%7E:text=Docker%20Compose%20examples) is the official odoo image example